# Specify class of link_to in embedded ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How would I specify the :class => "" here?:

```
<li><%= link_to "#" current_user  %></li>
```

TY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<li><%= link_to "#", current_user, :class => "class-name"  %></li>
```

Comment: Thank you Varatis, seems like a stupid question now, I guess I just had a syntax error :P

Answer (score 1):

Check following,

```
 <%= link_to "Articles", articles_path, :id => "news", :class => "article" %>
   # => <a href="/articles" class="article" id="news">Articles</a>
```

For more information, check:- http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to